# Ejected create-react-app works in Chrome/Firefox, blank in Safari

Tags: reactjs, safari, create-react-app

I'm working on a react app with create-react-app ejected (so that I can use css modules). It works perfectly in Chrome and nearly perfectly in Firefox (just need to make a few minor css adjustments), but in Safari, only the navbar is visible. Looking in the safari developer tools, http requests seem fine and there are no error messages. There are a few warnings about using Cloudinary images without http requests, but I get the same warnings in Chrome and the app still works fine in that browser.

Also, the images and elements that don't appear in the browser *do appear* in the elements section of the developer tools. The (now invisible) links even work. I thought maybe it was a z-index problem, so I set the background color to transparent, but the page is still blank. I'm not using the fetch API (per other suggestions on stackoverflow), and I tried adding -webkit- prefix to my css where applicable. In addition to css modules, I'm using styled-components.

Without error messages I really don't know where to start looking for a solution. Any ideas what could be causing this behaviour? I'm running the app on localhost and also Heroku, and am having the same problems with both methods.

Thanks!

Comment: Solution: apparently Safari deals with css positioning and z-index differently than Chrome and Firefox. I played with positioning (fixed, absolute, relative etc) so that everything appeared correctly on Safari, and the resulting arrangement also worked for Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Thanks for also posting the solution... I'm looking at doing this at some point and I looked at this in case I run into a similar problem. If you post it as an "answer" I'd vote up on it.

Comment: Glad it helped. Posted the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Solution: apparently Safari deals with css positioning and z-index differently than Chrome and Firefox. I played with positioning (fixed, absolute, relative etc) so that everything appeared correctly on Safari, and the resulting arrangement also worked for Chrome and Firefox.

Edit: But there are still positioning problems in Microsoft Edge, so I'll have to make adjustments for that, too.